# Subfolders in gcloud app engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud

Basically I want to use my app engine PHP project on my website. It works when I put one file in my main folder but I want to use subdirectories on my website. For example, if I want a forums I would make the url https://example.com/forums/whatever.php. Instead, I make subdirectories inside my main folder and when I access the directory listed above, it just gives me a 404 not found (nginx) error.

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /index
  static_dir: index

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /index/.*
  script: home.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the 404 is that you don't have an `app.yaml` handler with a pattern matching the `/forums/whatever.php` path. You need to add one.

I'd recommend changing the one you have now for the `home.php` script with the generic pattern covering any php script path from the `app.yaml` [Example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#example):

> ```
> # Serve php scripts.
> - url: /(.+\.php)$
>   script: \1
> ```

If you also want to have a default handler for an empty path you need to add it separately:

```
- url: /
  script: index.php
```

Comment: Since I can't properly format in a comment, here is a pastebin. The top is the directory and the bottom is the app.yaml code. I still get a 404 error upon visiting my site. https://pastebin.com/fB8M3uhT

Comment: Which path are you following while getting a 404 error? 

While Dan's answer is good, I can see in your `app.yaml` file that, if you hit the `/` path, you will get a 404 error. If you are hitting that path, you would need to add something like the following: 

`- url: /
  script: index.php`

Comment: This is the main problem now here: https://hastebin.com/dopiceyapa.md. Basically, I go to the website and my website appears perfectly fine. The files don't upload to App Engine. Instead, it gives me an error saying files were skipped. The files that are being skipped are in the forums folder. Inside that folder there are other folders that contain css, js, html, and php. Is there any way I can serve all of them so the files aren't skipped? I need them all in the same folder though. I need the php, html, css, and js to work in the same folders.

Comment: Can you please ask that as a separate question for clarity? Include your directory structure and (some of) those exact skipped messages. And describe what you mean by ' I need them all in the same folder': what you expect and what you see. Maybe reference this question for context.

Comment: I agree with @DanCornilescu , it should be good to accept his answer, as it solves the original question, and you can open a new question, with the new issue, as it can be better worked on there.